# python passing integer to c++ 64bit library: varying sizes

Tags: python, c++, int, ctypes

I am loading a 64bit c++ library in a python soft (also 64bit). The first trouble I noticed is that some of the integers passed to the library through the following protocole were not of the right size:

Python side:

```
c_int = c_int64
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.restype = None
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.argtypes = [c_void_p,POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),c_int,c_int,c_int,c_bool,POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)] 


self.polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython(self.dll,
                              self.btuplesDllFlat.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int)),
                              self.bterm.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int)),
                              len(self.bterm),
                              sum(self.bterm),
                              len(self.rangeX),
                              baseType,
                              self.coefficients.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)),
                              self.rangeX.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)),
                              self.minX.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)))
```

C++ side:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef __int64 int64_t;
#else
    #include <stdint.h>
#endif

DLL_EXPORT void loadComputationFromPython(PolynomialCurve* curve,__int64 *_btuple,
                     int *_bterm, int _btermSize,
                     int _Nvalidbtuple,int _Nparams,bool _polynomial,
                     double *_coefficients,
                     double *_rangeX,double *_minX) 
{
curve->loadComputationFromPython(_btuple,_bterm,_btermSize,_Nvalidbtuple,_Nparams,_polynomial,_coefficients,_rangeX,_minX);
}

void PolynomialCurve::loadComputationFromPython(__int64 *_btuple,
                     int *_bterm, int _btermSize,
                     int _Nvalidbtuple,int _Nparams,bool _polynomial,
                     double *_coefficients,
                     double *_rangeX,double *_minX) 
{
btermSize = _btermSize;
Nparams = _Nparams;
btuple = new int*[btermSize];
for (int i=0;i<btermSize;++i) {
    btuple[i] = new int[Nparams];
    for (int j=0;j<Nparams;++j) {
        btuple[i][j] = _btuple[i*Nparams+j];
    }
}
bterm = _bterm;
NvalidBtuple = _Nvalidbtuple;
polynomial = _polynomial;
coefficients = _coefficients;
rangeX = _rangeX;
minX = _minX;
}
```

I had to use the __int64 type in order to have correct integer type for `_btuple`. But the other int pointers seems still to be having trouble dealing with the integer size...

My question is how can I be coherent inside the c++ code to have all the int attributes always the same bit size? which size I want to be coherent with the c_int size in python. Is the __int64 type adequate for my problem? can I define pointers of __int64? should I be similarly carefull with doubles?

Those problem appeared when I changed from a 32 bit compilation to a 64 bit.
Thanks

**Edit:**
what has further be observed is that:

from python to c++: the python integers are 64bytes integers and I have to specify in C++ that the received integers are 64Bytes (using the __int64 type)

from C++ to python: the int type in C++ is a 32bytes integers, and when I recieve integers in python I have to specify its size with the c_int32 type:

```
addrBtuples = self.polynomialFittingDLL.getBtuples(self.dll)
self.btuplesDllFlat = np.ctypeslib.as_array((c_int32 * self.btuplesSize).from_address(addrBtuples))
```

So, in order to be as much portable as possible: should I "cast" the python int to a 32 bytes one? or should I force the c++ library to work with __int64 types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of int and double from the C side is implementation dependent (the standard only specifies the minimum size). So, it could depend on the compiler. Even though, there is in most cases a consistency between what ctypes python library does and what the C++ compiler does in the same platform.

So, to solve this, you need to change the sizes from the python side in a coherent way to get the proper casting. 
Given the C function signature in your case, I think that the following signature in the python side could work (only changing the first to c_longlong):

```
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.argtypes = [c_void_p,
                POINTER(c_longlong),
                POINTER(c_int),
                c_int,c_int,c_int,c_bool,
                POINTER(c_double),
                POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)]
```

But if your C++ compiler is augmenting the sizes of ints you should try:

```
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.argtypes = [c_void_p,
                POINTER(c_longlong),
                POINTER(c_long),
                c_long,c_long,c_long,c_bool,
                POINTER(c_double),
                POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)]
```

and if doubles are also augmented:

```
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.argtypes = [c_void_p,
                POINTER(c_longlong),
                POINTER(c_long),
                c_long,c_long,c_long,c_bool,
                POINTER(c_longdouble),
                POINTER(c_longdouble),POINTER(c_longdouble)]
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html for further information in all `ctypes` data types.

The point is that you need to check which is the casting that fits between ctypes and the compiled module.

I would recommend to test the border cases (long and integer maximum and minimum sizes, and the overflow) to see that everything is working properly.

Comment: I f I understand correctly your point, than the c library will always behave the same on all different computers. Thus the python side must be controlled to fit the requirements of the C library?

Comment: I replaced the `__int64` with `int` in the c++ library and I forced all int pointer to be of type `c_long`. This worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Yvus, quit the opposite. As I understand, provided the compiler satisfies the standard minimum sizes, it can augmented them. In the same platform, usually compilers behave the same, but that is not for sure. If you compiled a module with a different compiler than the used to compile CPython there is a change that the casting is not done correctly. But this is just a guess, that never happened to me. But apparently is what it is happening in this case, since longs from the python side have the same size as integers on the module side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you should not "shadow" `c_int` with `c_int64` : a `c_int` type is still 4 bytes on 64-bit

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)
4
```

The second argument should be a `POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)`:

```
# c_int = c_int64
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.restype = None
polynomialFittingDLL.loadComputationFromPython.argtypes = [c_void_p,POINTER(ctypes.c_int64),POINTER(c_int),c_int,c_int,c_int,c_bool,POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)]
```

Also, pointers keep the same size, whatever the type they points to.

Comment: I understand your point. This trick was only for allowing me to quickly change from one type to the other in the testing phase. Thanks